# How do I obtain the (possibly nested) capture groups in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a regular expression:

```
/say (hullo|goodbye) to my lovely (.*)/
```

and a string:

```
"my $2 is happy that you said $1"
```

What is the best way to obtain a regular expression from the string that contains the capture groups in the regular expression? That is:

```
/my (.*) is happy that you said (hullo|goodbye)/
```

Clearly I could use regular expressions on a string representation of the original regular expression, but this would probably present difficulties with nested capture groups.

I'm using Ruby. My simple implementation so far goes along the lines of:

```
class Regexp
  def capture_groups
    self.to_s[1..-2].scan(/\(.*?\)/)
  end
end

regexp.capture_groups.each_with_index do |capture, idx|
  string.gsub!("$#{idx+1}", capture)
end
/^#{string}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for looking - I've made the question clearer (I hope).

Comment: I don't see why this is being voted down or voted to close. To OP, you may just want to investigate existing regexp engines, or see if there's a way to peer inside the existing one (IIRC it's mostly C).

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm not especially comfortable in C! And I'm not sure why this was getting downvoted. Perhaps people didn't appreciate that this problem is more than simple string-munging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So once I realised that what I actually need is a regular expression parser, things started falling into place. I discovered this project:

- https://github.com/dche/randall

which can generate strings that match a regular expression. It defines a regular expression grammar using http://treetop.rubyforge.org/. Unfortunately the grammar it defines is incomplete, though useful for many cases.

I also stumbled past https://github.com/mjijackson/citrus, which does a similar job to Treetop.

I then found this mind blowing gem:

- https://github.com/ammar/regexp_parser

which defines a full regexp grammar and parses a regular expression into a walkable tree. I was then able to walk the tree and pick out the parts of the tree I wanted (the capture groups).

Unfortunately there was a minor bug, fixed in my fork: https://github.com/LaunchThing/regexp_parser.

Here's my patch to Regexp, that uses the fixed gem:

```
class Regexp
  def parse
    Regexp::Parser.parse(self.to_s, 'ruby/1.9')
  end

  def walk(e = self.parse, depth = 0, &block)
    block.call(e, depth)
    unless e.expressions.empty?
      e.each do |s| 
        walk(s, depth+1, &block) 
      end
    end
  end

  def capture_groups
    capture_groups = []
    walk do |e, depth|
      capture_groups << e.to_s if Regexp::Expression::Group::Capture === e
    end
    capture_groups
  end
end
```

I can then use this in my application to make replacements in my string - the final goal - along these lines:

```
from = /^\/search\/(.*)$/
to = '/buy/$1'

to_as_regexp = to.dup

# I should probably make this gsub tighter
from.capture_groups.each_with_index do |capture, idx|
  to_as_regexp.gsub!("$#{idx+1}", capture)
end
to_as_regexp = /^#{to_as_regexp}$/

# to_as_regexp = /^\/buy\/(.*)$/
```

I hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you need to create your own function that would do this:

- create empty dictionaries `groups` and `active_groups` and initialize `counter = 1`
- iterate over the characters in the string representation:

  - if current character = `'('` and previous charaster != `\`:

    - add `counter` key to `active_groups` and increase `counter`
  - add current character to all `active_groups`
  - if current character = `')'` and previous charaster != `\`:

    - remove the last item *(key, value)* from `active_groups` and add it to `groups`
- convert `groups` to an array if needed

---

You might also want to implement:

- `ignore = True` between unescaped `'['` and `']'`
- reset `counter` if current character = `'|'` and `active_groups` is empty *(or decrease `counter` if `active_group` is not empty)*

  **UPDATES** from comments:
- ingore non-capturing groups starting with `'(?:'`

Comment: yes, need to build enough of a parser to recognize capture groups. Note `(?:.*)` is not a capture.